# Create shapefile on Appengine preferably on Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, kml, shapefile, geotools

Hi i would like to create a shapefile(.shp .shx .prj .dbf) based on a KML file on appengine. My project is on java.

I tried to use geotools, and was able to create .shp .shx .prj on Appengine (with some changes on geotools to save on Google Cloud) but was not able  to create a .dbf with it. Geotools depends on AWT for creating the dbf, and Appengine restricts AWT.

Any sugestion on this? I´m starting even to consider calling a python module or something(never did anything like this). Or even creating just a dbf from a kml.

Thanks

Edit 1:
When i call `ShapefileDatastore.createSchema()` i have to pass a `SimpleFeatureType` as argument.

When i try to create a `SimpleFeatureType` or even use a `BasicFeatureTypes.POLYGON` it gave me error:

Caused by: 
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.RenderingHints is a restricted class. 
    Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at java.awt.RenderingHints.<clinit>(RenderingHints.java)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryFinder.<clinit>(FactoryFinder.java:35)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.<init>(ContentDataStore.java:173)
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore.<init>
    (ShapefileDataStore.java:124)
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStoreAppengine.<init>
    (ShapefileDataStoreAppengine.java:74)
    at brandeira.morholt.web.shared.util.ShapefileHelper.createShapefile(ShapefileHelpe
    r.java:121)`

I twisted a bit replacing `RenderingHints` by a non `awt RenderingHints` and them got another error:

Caused by: 
    `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry is a 
    restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.<clinit>(ServiceRegistry.java)
    at 
 org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder.getServiceRegistry(CommonFactoryFinder.java:76)
    at org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder.lookup(CommonFactoryFinder.java:346)
    at org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory(CommonFactoryFinder.java:300)
    at org.geotools.feature.AttributeTypeBuilder.<init>(AttributeTypeBuilder.java:192)
    at org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder.<init>(SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder.java:196)
    at org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder.<init>(SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder.java:186)
    at org.geotools.feature.type.BasicFeatureTypes.<clinit>(BasicFeatureTypes.java:101)
    at brandeira.morholt.web.shared.util.ShapefileHelper.createShapefile2(ShapefileHelper.java:290)`

It seems to use a lot of this factory methods of AWT (graphics is not the problem here in this case, just the use of AWT things).

I replaced that also and got:

Caused by: 
    `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProvider(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/google/apphosting/runtime/security/shared/stub/javax/imageio/spi/ServiceRegistry$Filter;Lorg/geotools/factory/Hints;Lorg/geotools/factory/Hints$Key;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder.lookup(CommonFactoryFinder.java:346)
    at org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory(CommonFactoryFinder.java:300)
    at org.geotools.feature.AttributeTypeBuilder.<init>(AttributeTypeBuilder.java:192)
    at org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder.<init>(SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder.java:196)
    at org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder.<init>(SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder.java:186)
    at org.geotools.feature.type.BasicFeatureTypes.<clinit>(BasicFeatureTypes.java:101)
    at brandeira.morholt.web.shared.util.ShapefileHelper.createShapefile2(ShapefileHelper.java:290)`

I could not yet find where this `javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry` (i have replaced all i found) is coming from and am thinking that i twisted this a lot and it doesn´t seem to be the way..

Comment: are you sure? I'm very surprised to hear that, can you provide a code sample and the error message